# Abridging \begin{} ... \end{}

Tags: environments

Is it possible to abbreviate the cumbersome commands `\begin{}...\end{}` once and for all?

I mean, except for `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`, I would like to have the environments such as `\begin{theorem}...\end{theorem}` become simply one-line command.

Comment: Wrap it up in an outer macro, but I am not sure this is possible for *any* environment. You have to use `{}` for the environment content then, however.

Comment: Updated with 'Generic' approach

Comment: I'd really recommend learning how to do this easily with your *editor* rather than trying to teach TeX how to do it. There's a fluid way to insert an environment (or wrap your selection with one) in most (if not all) editors made for LaTeX.

Comment: @SeanAllred: I coped without such editors ;-)

Comment: Don't do this; it *seems* practical, but it isn't in the long run.

Comment: Don't do this; it seems practical, but it isn't in the long run.

Comment: there are some environments for which this is absolutely impossible.  `verbatim` looks for the exact string `end{verbatim}` so it knows where to stop.  there are others, including the `amsmath` multi-line environments.  experimenting to find out which is mostly a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses an *environment* - wrapper, via `\NewDocumentCommand` from `xparse` package for possible better configurability (and `\par` content as argument values).

Possible vertical spacing issues are not addressed.

It's however not possible to say `\mytheorem{Title} content ...` since the environment needs a clear end.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] 


\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mytheorem}{+m+m}{%
  \begin{theorem}{#1}
    #2
  \end{theorem}
}


\begin{document}

\section{First}

\mytheorem{Theory on Brontosaurs, by Miss Ann Elk}{%

Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again at the other end.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit: Update ... a 'generic' wrapper command for such theorem environments**

This defines a generic wrapper command for such `newtheorem` issues:

`\GenericWrapper[section]{theoremname}{Theoremname}` will generate a command `\mytheoremname` with is wrapper for `\begin{theoremname}...\end{theoremname}` and reset every section (default value of the optional 1st. argument). (`xparse` is used with `\NewDocumentCommand` for this, in order to facilitate the usage of optional arguments in contrast to the `\newcommand[][]` way.)

The command changes the theorem label to `\arabic{theoremname}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\NewDocumentCommand{\GenerateWrapper}{+O{section}+m+m}{%
  \newtheorem{#2}{#3}[#1] 

  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname the#2\endcsname{\arabic{#2}}%

  \expandafter\DeclareDocumentCommand\csname my#2\endcsname{+m}{%
    \begin{#2}%
      ##1%
    \end{#2}
  }%
}%


\GenerateWrapper{theorem}{Theorem}%
\GenerateWrapper{exercise}{Exercise}%

\GenerateWrapper{question}{Question}%


\begin{document}


\section{First}

\mytheorem{%
Theory on Brontosaurs, by Miss Ann Elk%
Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again at the other end.
}%

\myexercise{Find a Brontosaur%

Excavate a Brontosaur
}%

\myquestion{Mathematics

Prove that  
\[ \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{\pi} \]
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's no point in using `xparse` for this. You use none of its features. I can't understand why you define `\mytheorem` with two arguments.

Comment: @egreg: `\xparse` for providing optional arguments? And some features not yet introduce, but later on.

Comment: Regarding "not possible" -- it is possible as long as it's only in topmost layer (and thus can change the catcode/endlinechar value)